# Missing main() prevents executable creation while linking

Tags: c, linker, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ on Windows. I compiled it fine without any errors. However, when I tried to execute it, I got two errors. I read the debugging errors, and I could not understand them. I am somewhat a newbie in C programming.

This code is from Kernighan and Ritchie's textbook on page 61:

```
#include <ctype.h>

/* atoi: convert s to integer; version 2 */
int atoi(char s[])
{
    int i, n, sign;

    for (i=0; isspace(s[i]); i++) /* skip white space */
        ;
    sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1: 1;
    if (s[i] == '+' || s[i] == '-') /* skip sign */
        i++;
    for (n=0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
        n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
    return sign*n;
}
```

The error:

```
--------------------Configuration: 3.5 - Win32 Debug--------------------
Linking... LIBCD.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main Debug/3.5.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals Error executing link.exe. 3.5.exe - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: `However, when I tried to execute it, I got two errors` Can you please post the full error message for the errors?

Comment: --------------------Configuration: 3.5 - Win32 Debug--------------------
Linking...
LIBCD.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main
Debug/3.5.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.

3.5.exe - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?!

Comment: I expect it to run counting the number of spaces, digits, and characters.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by reading chapter one of the K&R book ... ;-)

Comment: @JosephLee: Number of spaces, digits, and characters ... *of* *what*?!

Answer (score 5):

That's not a complete program. It's just a function. You can't execute it without writing some code to call it.

Comment: Which involves writing a `main`

Comment: Thank you, David. Exactly, how should I write inside the main?

Comment: @JosephLee: You should write code that does whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Every C program needs an entry point and `main()` provides that.

Please refer to the following:

- http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-importance-of-the-main-function-in-c-programmi.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how you wrote the entire `atoi` function, without knowing about importance of `main()`. :)
You should write a `main()` function and call your `atoi` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>//Required for printf used in main()
#include <ctype.h>

/* atoi: convert s to integer; version 2 */
int atoi(char s[])
{
    int i, n, sign;

    for (i=0; isspace(s[i]); i++) /* skip white space */
        ;
    sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1: 1;
    if (s[i] == '+' || s[i] == '-') /* skip sign */
        i++;
    for (n=0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
        n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
    return sign*n;
}


/* This is the part you've been missing. */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printf("%d\n",atoi("-100"));
   return 0;
}
```

I would also suggest you to: First try to write a hello world program in C++, then move to writing advanced stuff like this.